# Sublists/Multi-Layered Listbox? Also proper coding for this loop

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a listbox right now with the months January-December. I was wondering if there was a way to make it a sublist? So if they like checked Q1 then January-March would be checked.

Also I have this code right now:

```
  If audienceListbox.Selected(1) = True Then
  .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = "Yes"
  Else: .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = "No"
  End If
   If audienceListbox.Selected(2) = True Then
  .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = "Yes"
  Else: .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = "No"
  End If
   If audienceListbox.Selected(3) = True Then
  .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = "Yes"
  Else: .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = "No"
  End If
   If audienceListbox.Selected(4) = True Then
  .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = "Yes"
  Else: .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = "No"
  End If
   If audienceListbox.Selected(5) = True Then
  .Cells(iRow, 8).Value = "Yes"
  Else: .Cells(iRow, 8).Value = "No"
  End If
   If audienceListbox.Selected(6) = True Then
  .Cells(iRow, 9).Value = "Yes"
  Else: .Cells(iRow, 9).Value = "No"
  End If
   If audienceListbox.Selected(7) = True Then
  .Cells(iRow, 10).Value = "Yes"
  Else: .Cells(iRow, 10).Value = "No"
  End If
   If audienceListbox.Selected(8) = True Then
  .Cells(iRow, 11).Value = "Yes"
  Else: .Cells(iRow, 11).Value = "No"
  End If
   If audienceListbox.Selected(9) = True Then
  .Cells(iRow, 12).Value = "Yes"
  Else: .Cells(iRow, 12).Value = "No"
  End If
   If audienceListbox.Selected(10) = True Then
  .Cells(iRow, 13).Value = "Yes"
  Else: .Cells(iRow, 13).Value = "No"
  End If
   If audienceListbox.Selected(11) = True Then
  .Cells(iRow, 14).Value = "Yes"
  Else: .Cells(iRow, 14).Value = "No"
  End If
   If audienceListbox.Selected(12) = True Then
  .Cells(iRow, 15).Value = "Yes"
  Else: .Cells(iRow, 15).Value = "No"
  End If
```

Is there a better way to write this loop? Right now I am getting an error on the 12th selected property saying it can't locate it even though I have 12 options on my list (January-December).

Sorry I just started using VBA yesterday so I'm still figuring out the basics.

Comment: I think the `Selected` property starts at 0 so you need to use 0-11 instead of 1-12

Comment: That solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option for a rewrite.

As for grouping columns together, it looks you like that's being done by quarters (calendar)?

If true, you could be selecting by quarters instead. If you want a custom grouping, add the groupings to an 2 dimensional array and loop over them.

```
Public Sub Tester()
    Dim MonthNumber  As Byte
    Dim ColumnNumber As Integer: ColumnNumber = 4

    For MonthNumber = 0 To 11
        If audienceListbox.Selected(MonthNumber) Then
            Cells(iRow, ColumnNumber).Value = "Yes"
        Else
            Cells(iRow, ColumnNumber).Value = "No"
        End If
        'Increase the column Index for each time through the loop
        ColumnNumber = ColumnNumber + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, this works out perfectly! Thanks so much.

On the idea of grouping, yes I am doing it by quarters (Q1-Q4). 

So what do you mean by array and groupings? I have little to no VBA experience so I'm trying to learn as much as I can. I'm trying to make it so that the text that is the same on every column is merged together so it's the same text over the months or quarters. Is that what you're referring to?

Here is what my spreadsheet and calendar looks like: http://imgur.com/a/a6Ckm